# Why Python and Node.js's HMAC result is different in this code?

Tags: python, node.js, hmac

Recently, I have a task to make HMAC to communicate API server.
I got a sample code of node.js version which makes HMAC of message. Using concept and sample, I've got to make a python code which is equivalent with node.js version but result is different, but I have no idea why.

Please review both code and help finding the difference.

**Python 3.0**

```
import hmac
import string
import hashlib
import base64

secret = 'PYPd1Hv4J6'
message = '1515928475.417'
key = base64.b64encode(secret.encode('utf-8'))

hmac_result = hmac.new(key, message.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha512)
print(base64.b64encode(hmac_result.digest()))
```

Result (Python 3.6)

```
b'7ohDRJGMGYjfHojnrvNpM3YM9jb+GLJjbQvblzrE17h2yoKfIRGEBSjfOqQFO4iKD7owk+gSciFxFkNB+yPP4g=='
```

**Node.JS**

```
var crypto = require('crypto');

var secret = 'PYPd1Hv4J6';
var message = '1515928475.417'
var key = Buffer(secret, 'base64');

var hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha512', key);
var hmac_result = hmac.update(message).digest('base64');
console.log(hmac_result)
```

Result (Node.JS 6.11)

```
m6Z/FxI492VXKDc16tO5XDNvty0Tmv0b1uksSbiwh87+4rmg43hEXM0WmWzkTP3aXB1s5rhm05Hu3g70GTrdEQ==
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your input keys are different, so the outputs will be different.

Node:

```
var secret = 'PYPd1Hv4J6';
var message = '1515928475.417'
var key = Buffer(secret, 'base64'); // buffer of bytes from the base64-encoded string 'PYPd1Hv4J6'
                                    //  <Buffer 3d 83 dd d4 7b f8 27>
```

Python:

```
secret = 'PYPd1Hv4J6'
message = '1515928475.417'
key = base64.b64encode(secret.encode('utf-8')) # did you mean b64decode here?
```

Comment: I tried to make base64 encoded `secret` so I used `base64.b64encode`. And b64decode has an error as `binascii.Error: Incorrect padding`

Comment: base64 strings must be a multiple of 3 characters long, so changing `secret` to `'PYPd1Hv4J6=='` should work with `b64decode`. Node's `Buffer` doesn't seem to care that it received incorrect padding :)

Comment: `secret = 'PYPd1Hv4J6=='`
`key = base64.b64decode(secret.encode('utf-8'))` works, thanks. I can step ahead.

Comment: Node's malfunction of padding calculation was amazed to me that python could check. It is a kind of bug?

Comment: RFC 4648 says " Implementations MUST include appropriate pad characters at the end of encoded data unless the specification referring to this document explicitly states otherwise." So it depends on how Node documented its behavior.

Comment: Round-tripping adds the correct padding in for you:
`Buffer('PYPd1Hv4J6', 'base64').toString('base64')`
->
`'PYPd1Hv4Jw=='`

Note that this isn't the same  as the initial input with some `==`s tacked on.

Comment: So, in the Python version, you might need to set `secret = 'PYPd1Hv4Jw=='`

Comment: Yes indeed. I posted desired answer.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to get them to match by stripping out the `base64`ing of everything:

**Python:**

```
import hmac
import string
import hashlib
import base64

secret = 'PYPd1Hv4J6'
message = '1515928475.417'
key = secret.encode('utf-8')

hmac_result = hmac.new(key, message.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha512)
print(base64.b64encode(hmac_result.digest()))
```

Output:

```
b'jezLNuBz37FoACm4LdLSqOQ5C93cuGID9a8MQmOZntXklDV3SvWdNfqndzK0a54awKeHY+behFiv4FYyILRoGQ=='
```

**Javascript**:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');

var secret = 'PYPd1Hv4J6';
var message = '1515928475.417'

var hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha512', secret);
var hmac_result = hmac.update(message).digest('base64');
console.log(hmac_result)
```

Output:

```
jezLNuBz37FoACm4LdLSqOQ5C93cuGID9a8MQmOZntXklDV3SvWdNfqndzK0a54awKeHY+behFiv4FYyILRoGQ==
```

Comment: Sample Node.JS code has `var key = Buffer(secret, 'base64');` which looks like important. Can Python follow that convention ?

Comment: `Buffer(secret, 'base64')` meant decode `secret` as 'base64'. I misunderstood the code and spent some time. Now I can fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Equivalent/Expected python code's is below.

```
import hmac
import string
import hashlib
import base64

secret = 'PYPd1Hv4J6=='
message = '1515928475.417'
key = base64.b64decode (secret.encode('utf-8'))

hmac_result = hmac.new(key, message.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha512)
print(base64.b64encode(hmac_result.digest()))
```

Padding '=' to targeted and decoding part was important.
Thank you.